# Proper way of implementing the DB queries to read and write MySQL replicas in the node.js project?

Tags: mysql, node.js, database-replication

I have a node.js express project that uses MySQL 5.6 database and `mysql` client to connect to it. There is no ORM in the project, the raw queries are run against the DB. Now, I need to change the code in the way that `SELECT` queries (that are not within the transaction) would be routed to the MySQL read replica. Since I have never previously done anything similar on any other projects, I was wondering what are the best practices of doing it (in the node.js).

I have found that the `sequelize` library has the configuration option that allows to specify read and write replicas separately and then different queries would be routed to the different databases, but I haven't found any options of doing it in the `mysql` client library. I tried using `sequelize`, but it seems that for RAW queries this feature is not supported.

Apart from that, I am wondering what would be the best solution from the architectural standpoint? Currently, the only option that I see is having some database wrapper service that has `query` method, that, in turn, encapsulates the `mysql` `connection.query` and based on the sql provided to it decides which database connection to use - read or write (unless it's a transaction - then everything should be done in the same DB, I guess). It's a rather dumb solution, but it's my only idea now.

Could anyone please share some experience on this? Not only in node.js projects - any architectural ideas are welcome. Maybe there is some way of proxying the requests before it gets to the host? Thanks for any answer in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, eventually, I have solved it in a rather straightforward way: created separate connection pools for read and write DB replicas and used each of them directly in places, that I needed:

```
const writePool = mysql.createPool(writeConnectionString);
const readPool = mysql.createPool(readConnectionString);

function getWriteConnection() {
    return writePool.getConnection();
};

async function getReadConnection() {
    const connection = await readPool.getConnection();
    connection.isRead = true;
    const originalQuery = connection.query;
    connection.query = function (...args) {
        if(!isSelectQuery(args[0])) {
            throw new Error('Read connection cannot be used for the commands other than SELECT.');
        }

        return originalQuery.apply(this, args);
    };

    return connection;
};

// checking if query is SELECT
function isSelectQuery(query) {
    return query.replace(/\s+/mi, '').toLowerCase().startsWith('select');
}

// release function
function release(connection) {
    if(connection.isRead) {
        readPool.releaseConnection(connection)
    } else {
        writePool.releaseConnection(connection);
    }
};
```

Then in code:

```
const connection = await database.getReadConnection();
await connection.query('SELECT * FROM ...');
....
database.release(connection);
```

This is far not the most elegant way to solve it, but it relatively quickly solved my problem with minimal changes and subsequent bugs.